# SWI Prolog - variable name and variable value

Tags: prolog

I got a little problem with Prolog. I hope you guys can help me!

'Find' does look in List for the Index (e.g. 4) and puts the answer in Return.
find(Liste, Index, Return).

The output is something like:

> Output element: four
>   Output result: _G2360.

I guess _G2360 is the internal name of the variable?
What do I have to do to get:

> Output result: four.

The segment of the code:

```
   [...]
   find(List,4,Return),
   write("Output result: ",Return).

find([Element|_],0,Element):-
   write("Output element: ",Element).
find([_|List],N,_) :-
   N1 is N-1,
   find(List,N1,_).
```

Thanks!
Sorry for the bad title I can't think of a good one that puts the problem in a few meaningful words.

Comment: write/2 will produce an error with these arguments, it never outputs _G2360 or four

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recursive clause of your `find` does not pass `Element` to the recursive invocation, which is causing the issue that you are seeing: the "don't care" variable that you pass in place of the `Element` becomes the `_G2360` in your output, because it unifies to anything.

Here is how you can fix this:

```
find([Element|_],0,Element).
find([Head|List], N, Element) :- N1 is N-1, find(List, N1, Element).
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/GBCTZ6)

Comment: This is correct. Just to add, I guess the `write` in the first clause to `find` is altogether unnecessary, since OP is doing it after evaluating `find` anyway.

Comment: @Boris Thanks! I realized the same thing when I was composing a demo, so I deleted the `write` in the first clause.